# .htaccess rules to ignore the main directory .htaccess file if specific subfolder is requested in URI

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdirectory

I have three subfolders `/software1/`, `/software2/` and `/software3/` for three different applications in the main root directory for `domain.com`. The `.htaccess` rules for these subfolders are interfering with the `.htaccess` file in the main directory. So, I wonder if there is a rule to add into the `.htaccess` file in the main directory to ignore the rest of the file and directly jump into the `/software1/`, `/software2/` and `/software3/` subfolders (i.e. their `.htaccess` files) if URI is `http://domain.com/software1/...`, `http://domain.com/software2/...` and `http://domain.com/software3/...`?

Comment: You could put the rules specific to each subfolder into a `.htaccess` file in each subfolder? So `software1/` would have it's own `htaccess` file etc

Answer (score 2):

It would have been nice to see your current .htaccess rules so we can see what it's doing or not doing. But if you just want to not do anything for the 3 directories, you can try this in the main .htaccess and just have it not do anything if it is one of those 3 directories.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(software1|software2|software3)$ - [L,NC]
```